# Is there a way of keeping track of the relationship between vertices and pixels using either OpenGL or DirectX? 11

Tags: opengl, directx, 3d

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a single static image of a 3D object (1 single object represented as a triangle list), using OpenGL or DirectX, that allows you to know which specific triangles defining the object have been used to generate every one of  the pixels forming the rendered image. I've cited OpenGL and DirectX because they are widely used APIs graphics if somebody knows other ways of achieving the previous that works at high speed I would be also interested in his/her answer. I currently use my own software implementation of the rendering pipeline to keep track of the relationship, but I would like to use the power and effects (mainly antialiasing, shadows and specific skin rendereing techniques) that graphics cards offer.

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 5):

Sure, just output a triangle identifier to a separate render-target (using MRT). In GLSL-terms, this is [gl_PrimitiveID](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_PrimitiveID.xml), and in HLSL-terms it's [SV_PrimitiveID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#PrimitiveID). If you are using multi-sampling, then your multi-sample buffer for that render-target become a list of primitives that contribute to each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Draw each triangle in a different colour. R8G8B8 offers you about 16.7 million possible colours, so one can index that number of triangles with it. You don't have to draw to a on-screen buffer. You could render the picture as usual, and render to a second target, indexing the triangles in a off-screen buffer.